# Multiplying vector elements

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a vector and I want to multiply some of its values by a number and assign that result to another vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> digits[NUMBER_OF_DIGITS - 1];
std::vector<int> new_digits[NUMBER_OF_DIGITS - 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_DIGITS; i + 2) {
        //multiplication that fails
        new_digits[i] = digits[i] * 2;
    }
```

The error I get is that "no operator "*" matches these operands"

The other questions on this site are either to advanced for me(like the once using transform?) or not applicable to my situation.

Comment: You made arrays of vectors, instead of making a vector with a given size. What you meant to do was: `std::vector<int> v(NUMBER_OF_DIGITS - 1);`

Comment: Also : you might consider std valarry